# Cite a Foreword in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

How do I cite a foreword in BibTeX? I would like the citation below to be "Hornstein 2005", but I would like the bibliography to also mention Chomsky. I am using `@InCollection". Is this correct?

```
@InCollection{hornstein2005chomsky,
  author    = {Hornstein, Norbert},
  title     = {Chomsky's Natural Philosophy},
  booktitle = {Rules and Representations},
  year      = {2005},
  publisher = {Columbia University Press},
}
```

Comment: I do not see where there is a foreword. Furthermore you do not cite in bibtex, but in tex oder latex using bibtex to manage the references. 
In addition, if you want to cite the title of the work, you could use jurabib, that has a \citetitle(only) command.

Comment: If Biblatex is an option, it has special facilities for this. Otherwise, you need to add the author for `booktitle` etc. in the usual way.

Comment: The purpose of a bibliography item is to point the reader to a source where to find the cited material. The foreword is part of some book, which you refer to as such; when citing, you say something “see Smith's foreword in [1]”. Some books are made of separate contributions, so you can and should use `@incollection` or similar type; but a foreword is not the same thing.

Comment: @egreg - In this case, I do want to treat it as a separate contribution. How should I go about that?

Comment: @Adam_G Maybe you want to, but that's not what bibliographies are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution: add the details to either the author list or to the title, etc, depending on how the bibliography style mangles the format. For example, using the author list:

```
@book{knuth-foreword,
    author={Knuth, DE and 
        {Foreword in Petkov{\v s}ek, M, Wilf, HS, Zeilberger, D}}, 
    title={A=B}, 
    publisher={A K Peters},
    year=1996
}
```

Note how Knuth is automatically formatted by the Bibtex style, but the other authors have to be styled manually. (This is the Royal Society author style:-)

The best solution would be adding `{foreword}` to the BST file, but that takes knowing how to program Bibtex, and also is less portable because it creates a quirky bibliography style. Unfortunately the workaround here isn't robust against someone changing the bibliography style, as the author formatting details may change. Well, that's workarounds for you.

Sometimes you can use `note={....}` but styles often put the note in the wrong place to help with a foreword.